# How I can change laravel created_at format to diffForHumans() in model casting

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, eloquent, php-carbon

I want to change laravel default created_at format to diffForHumans() in model. I can change it to other formats like below

```
protected $casts = [
   'created_at' => 'datetime:H:i d M, Y', // Out put 03:40 09 Dec, 2022
];
```

But I want it to diffForHumans() format. like below

```
protected $casts = [
   'created_at' => $this->created_at->diffForHumans(), // Out put should 2 days ago
];
```

But I can't do it. Right now I'm using laravel 9

Thanks in advance :) 
Sakib

Comment: Have you tried using a mutator instead of casting?

Comment: I guess, simple getter/Mutator  will solve the issue. 

function getCreatedAt() {
return $this->created_at->diffForHumans()

Comment: @AlexanderDyriavin I did but not working  ` public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
    }`

Comment: Have you removed casts from the attribute?